# Image flip on hover just reflecting image, and not actually flipping

Tags: html, css, image, hover, flip

The site is 3peak.us and I am currently trying to display the 3 image flip divs evenly across the page. I would also like it to be responsive.

Ive tried putting them all in one div that is 100% width and then making each one 30% but it does not seem to work. When I would make them 30% they were becoming 30% of the actual image div and not the whole page.

This is the css coding for the divs.

```
.threeflips {
  width: 100%;
}

.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
width: 30%;
float: left;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper,  
  .flip-container.hover .flipper {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
}

.flipper {
-webkit-transition: 0.6s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

-moz-transition: 0.6s;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  -o-transition: 0.6s;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

transition: 0.6s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;

position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;

position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.front {
background: url(https://www.3peaks.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/1front.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
z-index: 2;
}

.back {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);

background: url(https://www.3peaks.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/1back.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}









.bflip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
float: left;
width: 30%;
}

.bflip-container:hover .bflipper,  
  .bflip-container.hover .bflipper {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.bflip-container, .bfront, .bback {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
}

.bflipper {
-webkit-transition: 0.6s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

-moz-transition: 0.6s;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  -o-transition: 0.6s;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

transition: 0.6s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;

position: relative;
}

.bfront, .bback {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;

position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.bfront {
background: url(https://www.3peaks.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/2front.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
z-index: 2;
}

.bback {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);

background: url(https://www.3peaks.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/2back.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}






.cflip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
width: 30%;
float: left;
}

.cflip-container:hover .cflipper,  
  .cflip-container.hover .cflipper {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.cflip-container, .cfront, .cback {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
}

.cflipper {
-webkit-transition: 0.6s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

-moz-transition: 0.6s;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  -o-transition: 0.6s;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

transition: 0.6s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;

position: relative;
}

.cfront, .cback {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;

position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.cfront {
background: url(https://www.3peaks.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3front.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
z-index: 2;
}

.cback {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);

background: url(https://www.3peaks.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3back.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

and here is the html

```
<div class="threeflips">
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
    </div>
    <div class="back">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="bflip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="bflipper">
    <div class="bfront">
    </div>
    <div class="bback">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="cflip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="cflipper">
    <div class="cfront">
    </div>
    <div class="cback">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As soon as I change .flip-container, .front .back with to 30% it makes all of them just disappear. So the only way Ive gotten them to display is with a set px width but then theyre no longer responsive.

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/pgrovefd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you change the .front, .back to 30% ? both .front and .back should be 100% width and just the .flip-container should be 30% or 33.33% depending on your design

```
.flip-container {
width: 33.33%;
height: 400px;
}
.front, .back {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;}
```

so separate the .flip-container styles from .front and .back styles, your code has been edited as per your brief and available on **[codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gabWzY)**

Comment: I have one more question though.... is there a way to make the height responsive as well?